# DAO Layer Code Review

Tags: java, database

Please review my following code for DAO layer.

```
public List<Channel> getListOfChannels() throws DataAccessException {
        // will have the channel in form of List
        // to hold the channels list
        List<Channel> listChannels = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            // get the db connection from pool
                // this is DBCP lib on top doing this 
            conn = ManageConnections.getConnection();
            statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            final String QUERY_STRING = "Select * from channel";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(QUERY_STRING);

            // is this good practice to put this ?
            if (isResultSetEmptyOrNull(resultSet)) {
                throw new DataAccessException(
                        "No more data of Channels found from db");
            }

            Channel channel = null;

            listChannels = new ArrayList<Channel>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                // get the object from the result set and 


                listChannels.add(channel);
            }

            log.debug("getListOfChannels Got the list of channels "
                    + listChannels);

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DataAccessException(SQL_EXCEPTION + ex, ex);
        } catch (DBConnectionException ex) {
            // re thrown, no logging
            throw new DataAccessException(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Generic exception thrown , now throw Custom Exceptionn
            throw new DataAccessException(GENERIC_EXCEPTION + ex, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    // this is DBCP lib on top doing this 
                    ManageConnections.close(conn);
                }
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                if (resultSet != null) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new DataAccessException(
                        "Exception while closing resource" + ex, ex);
            } catch (DBConnectionException ex) {
                throw new DataAccessException(
                        "Exception while closing resource" + ex, ex);
            }
        }

        return listChannels;
```

Comment: Even if this code was perfect, what is your plan for avoiding repeating it?

Comment: Do you have Java 7? Then an ARM block would be helpful.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca didnt get you ?

Comment: @Landei Nope! we didnt migrated to Java7 yet.

Comment: @ajduke Opening/closing resources (connections, transactions, statements, resultsets) and exception handling etc, which are almost all the code you've provided, are common to all data access methods; and *somehow* should be refactored out. All you should need to write in a dao implementation is something like `em.createQuery("select c from Channel c").toResultList()`

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca yes, true! Will refactored it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of improvements that can be made here:

- a) your QUERY_STRING is magic string. Move it to a different place,
  because it make your code difficult to maintain
- user linked list
  instead of array list. It has O(1) on insertion in worst case,
  whereas array list has O(n)
- do not rethrow exceptions in finally
  block. You will lose all details of your original exception
- every time when you concatenate strings with "+" you make too many
  operations with memory, because strings are immutable. use *.format
  instead

Comment: can you explain more on "why not to rethrow in finally block" ?

Comment: Can you explain more on "why not to rethrow in finally block" ? Your finally will get executed no matter what. Any SQL Exception thrown in finally block will discard exceptions thrown before.